# Two SurfaceView, How can i get the click event about the below SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have two SurfaceView. big SurfaceView is below to the small SurfaceView. the small SurfaceView can move everywhere. when i use setZOrderOnTop(true),when i click the big SurfaceView,it doesn't work, the click event can not be got. Is there some suggestions?
The code is following:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth() - 1, getScreenHeight() - 1);
                    surfaceViewLarge = surfaceView;
                    surfaceViewLarge.setZOrderOnTop(false);
                    surfaceViewLarge.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
                    frameLayout.addView(surfaceViewLarge, 0, frameParams);

                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 420);
                    params.leftMargin = getScreenWidth() - 380;
                    params.topMargin = 360;
                    surfaceViewLittle.setLayoutParams(params);
                    surfaceViewLittle.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                    surfaceViewLittle.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
                    frameLayout.addView(surfaceViewLittle);
```

i found the question is that i used setZOrderOnTop(true),when i set false,the click event can be got,but the small SurfaceView will not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,i have solved it. as react native view intercepts the click event.